# How can I back up my Drupal site?

Tags: 7, backups

My site crashed the other day, and I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I can back up my site, so that if something ever goes wrong again, I could still have a working copy of my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Backup and Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate):

> Backup and Migrate simplifies the task of backing up and restoring your Drupal database or copying your database from one Drupal site to another. It supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.

Comment: perfect! exactly what I need!

Comment: You still need to backup your files using FTP or some other method. Backup and migrate just andles the database.

Comment: True, its companion module http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_files can help with the files directory, and then FTP or other method for your themes, modules, and core.